# Is there a way to have a python guidata dataitem activated by more than one dataitem attribute function property?

Tags: python, user-interface

I would like a python [guidata](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/guidata) dataitem to be activated based on the property of more than one other ChoiceItem attribute function. Is there a way to link together the properties of ChoiceItems to affect the activation of another dataitem in the interface?

For example, in the output from the below code, I would like the interface to activate 'Choice D' if 'Choice B' is toggled True, even if 'Choice A' is set to 'A2'. At the moment, 'Choice D' only activates if 'Choice A' is NOT set to 'A2', because the 'Choice D' ChoiceItem is linked only to the property affected by 'Choice A'.

```
import sys
import guidata.dataset.datatypes as gdt
import guidata.dataset.dataitems as gdi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


# initialise QApplication
_in_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class Input(gdt.DataSet):
    
    _prop1 = gdt.GetAttrProp('select_chA')
    choicesA = (('a1', "A1"), ('a2', "A2"))
    select_chA = gdi.ChoiceItem("Choice A:", choicesA, default='a2').set_prop('display', store=_prop1)
        
    _prop2 = gdt.GetAttrProp('select_chB')
    select_chB = gdi.BoolItem("Choice B:", default=False).set_prop('display', store=_prop2)
    choicesC = (('c1', "C1"),('c2', "C2"))
    select_chC = gdi.ChoiceItem("Choice C:",
                                choicesC).set_prop('display',
                                                   active=gdt.FuncProp(_prop2,
                                                                       lambda x: x != False))
    choicesD = (('d1', "D1"), ('d2', "D2"), ('d3', "D3"))
    
    select_chD = gdi.ChoiceItem("Choice D:",
                                choicesD).set_prop('display', active=gdt.FuncProp(_prop1,
                                                                        lambda x: x == 'a1'))
inputs = Input()
input_dialog = inputs.edit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Guidata library seems to be an opinionated one. As always for such libraries, you need a hacky solution if you want a feature that's not readymade.

In this case, you can use the undocumented `ItemProperty`. Its constructor expects a callable argument, which is called when the property is evaluated. (See [the source](https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/guidata/blob/v2.3.1/guidata/dataset/datatypes.py#L38) for details.) So, do like the following example.

```
...
import guidata.dataset.datatypes as gdt
import guidata.dataset.dataitems as gdi
...
class Input(gdt.DataSet):
    
    _prop1 = gdt.GetAttrProp('select_chA')
    ...
    select_chA = gdi.ChoiceItem(...).set_prop('display', store=_prop1)

    _prop2 = gdt.GetAttrProp('select_chB')
    select_chB = gdi.BoolItem(...).set_prop('display', store=_prop2)

    ...
    select_chD = gdi.ChoiceItem(...).set_prop('display', active=
        gdt.ItemProperty(lambda *args:
            Input._prop1(*args) == 'a1' or Input._prop2(*args)))
...
```